# Facebook bot messages not showing blank lines

Tags: facebook, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have created a chat bot using Microsoft bot framework and deployed it on Azure and linked it with my Facebook page. Everything is working fine but has a minor issue that, One of the messages send by the bot has a combination of 2-3 different lines, I want to show those 3 lines separated by blank lines  so I have added escape sequence "\n\n" between the lines.

```
"Line1\n\nLine2\n\nLine3"
```

This works fine when I testes it in Azure web chat but Facebook chat window don't display the blank lines, Can any one help me with this?Thanks in Advance.

Currently face Display message like

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

I want to show it as

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

Comment: Try putting a space at the beginning of those blank lines maybe. If that doesn’t work either, try what results you get with a displayable character, like a dot or an underscore.

Comment: Did you try to double your `\n\n`? I know it seems strange, but I also found that you need to double `\n` on some channels, so maybe for FB Messenger you have to double both. And in that case, you can force that by checking the `channelId`, to ensure that you have `\n\n\n\n` for FB and `\n\n` in other channels

Comment: @NicolasR, Yes I tried That, dose not any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your message text is being run through a rather aggressive Markdown parser that's stripping away extra line breaks. You have a few options for how to deal with this.

### Option 1

If you set the text as channel data instead of the actual activity text, it won't be run through the Markdown parser:

```cs
var text = "Line1\n\nLine2\n\nLine3";
var activity = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
activity.ChannelData = new { text };
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity);
```

### Option 2

If you set the text format to plain, the text won't be run through the Markdown parser:

```cs
var text = "Line1\n\nLine2\n\nLine3";
var activity = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply(text);
activity.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity);
```

### Option 3

If you're using channel data for something else and you don't want to set the text format to plain, you can always use `<br/>` instead of `\n`:

```cs
var text = "Line1<br/><br/>Line2<br/><br/>Line3";
```